# How can I convert nested array of object to non-nested objects with specific key name

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

How can I convert nested array of object to non-nested objects with specific key name:

```
data = [{department: 'IT', total: 7, planned: 5, 
    units: [
    {name: 'HR', total: 30, planned: 5, description: 'HR Admin'},
    {name: 'Sales', total: 4, planned: 9, description: 'Sales Admin'}
    ]
    }]
```

my required output should be:

```
data = [
{name: 'IT', total: 7, planned: 5, description: ''},
{name: 'HR', total: 30, planned: 5, description: 'HR Admin'},
{name: 'Sales', total: 4, planned: 9, description: 'Sales Admin'}
]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+convert+nested+array+object+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) together with the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) can achieve the desired result.

```js
const data = [
  {
    department: 'IT',
    total: 7,
    planned: 5,
    units: [
      {
        name: 'HR',
        total: 30,
        planned: 5,
        description: 'HR Admin'
      },
      {
        name: 'Sales',
        total: 4,
        planned: 9,
        description: 'Sales Admin'
      }
    ]
  }
];

const result = data.flatMap(( obj ) => {
  return [
    {
      name: obj.department,
      total: obj.total,
      planned: obj.planned,
      description: '',
    },
    ...obj.units,
  ];
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: sorry, but now aware of the method flatMap, thank you